# How can I change a toolbox item property by referring to the item through a variable?

Tags: vb.net, string

Sorry for the confusing title - here is the code I'm using.

Example code -

```
    If bolCorrect = False Then
        intIncorrect += 1
        temp3 = "picture" + CStr(intIncorrect)
        temp3.Visible = True
```

I've got several images all, with names of picture[number-from-0-to-10], and I want them to show depending on the count of a variable.

The error it throws up is that 'Visible' is not part of 'String'. How can I get the interpreter to look at 'temp3' in this instance, and refer to the toolbox item rather than the type of the variable (e.g. string)?

Comment: Another remark: `If something = False Then` is redundant. Write it as `If Not something Then`. It never (!) makes sense to compare a variable with a boolean literal (`True`/`False`). Those literals are only useful to initialise a boolean variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to the actual name property you have set for the picturebox control (if you are using the picturebox control)
So if your picture box control is named pb1

```
pb1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("picture" + counter + ".jpg")
pb1.Visible = True
```

Comment: This isn’t what the OP is after, and it won’t compile.

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot the System.Drawing.Image.FromFile method

Answer (score 0):

You should generally try to *avoid* addressing controls via strings, that’s usually just a hack around a proper solution. Instead, maintain a variable *to that control*, or, in your case, maintain an array of the relevant controls and access them via an index.

That said, it *is* possible to get a control given its name via the [`Form.Controls` collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx):

```
Dim ctl = Me.Controls("picture" + CStr(intIncorrect))
```